# GAE JPA Embedded Annotation Issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Ok so I have an Entity School.

```
@Entity 
public class School implements Serializable 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -854333301529125138L;
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long ID;  
private String Type;
private String Name;
private String City;
private String Country;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Info information;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="school",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Contact> Contacts;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="school",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
// more fields and getters and setters.
```

The Student Class contains lots of student information, and the student transcripts and is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5426530769458891752L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key ID;
@ManyToOne 
private School school;
private long SID;
private final long TSTAMP;
private String FName;
private String LName;
private String Email;
private String SchoolName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private StudentInfo studentInf = new StudentInfo ();
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Transcript transcript;
 // more fields and getters and setters.
```

the Transcript Class in the Student Class is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Transcript
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key ID;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="transcript",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Student student;
@Embedded 
private Course1 c1;
@Embedded 
private Course2 c2;
@Embedded 
private Course3 c3;
//... ect
public Transcript()
{
    this.c1= new Course1();
    this.c2= new Course2();
    this.c3= new Course3();
    // ... ect
}

// more fields and getters and setters.
```

and finally here is a sample course class

```
@Embeddable
public class Course1 implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7643055124732162110L;

private final String CourseTitle = "Course 1 Title";
private boolean MileStone1 = false;
private boolean MileStone2 = false;
// ... ect ... getters and setters
}
```

All the classes Enhance without a problem and the server runs, but as soon as a Student Instance is created, it results in a total catastrophe in GAE dev server and I have tried alot of possible options with the same error message:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: You have a field db.Entity.student.Student.transcript that has type db.Entity.Courses.Transcript but this type has no known metadata. Your mapping is incorrect"
```

I would very very much appreciate an explanation on why this is happening and how to fix it while keeping the logical relations

Comment: if some type (Transcript) has no known metadata then work out WHY it has no metadata? excluded it from persistence.xml "class" definitions perhaps? Not sure how that rates as a "total catastrophe" ...

Comment: no it is in the persistence.xml ... not excluded, Thanks alot, but some credit pleaaaseee !! :)

Comment: that's where looking at the log is the next step.

Comment: Hey Thanks alot !! I have been checking the error trace but I cant seem to get any where with it ... would you mind taking a look at it ?? btw I cant edit the question anymore to post it ... so inbox or email or new question and post the link here ???